# 500 SSL read timeout error in LWP perl

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I have a `perl` script which will post HTTP request to specified server URL (Say: `http://some-ip/here_action_url` ). My problem is, Sometimes I am getting the below error.

**Error:**

```
500 SSL read timeout.
```

**Sample Code:**

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->timeout(30);
my $res = $ua->post( $url, { 'data' => $my_data } );
if(! $res->is_success ) {
     # Error Logging
     print $res->status_line."\n";
}
else {
     $response_content = $res->content;
}
```

I read about the error. Most of the documents are saying that it is because of the response delay in server side.

I just want to confirm, whether this error is coming because of server response delay? (or) Can be the problem with my perl script?

Answer (score 1):

If you get a result some of the time, and the error at other times, then it looks like your code is working.

If you alway get the 500 error, it indicates a connection problem. Would need to know more about the service you are trying to connect to, does it require certificates or other authentication (which may be needed for secure socket layer connection)